# How to eliminate just pair duplicates in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

After reading mostly all the questions related to pair duplicates, no question address the following issue:

Given a Df:

```
   Letter
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   a
5   b
6   a
7   a
8   a
```

Eliminate only pairs of duplicates. For example: as the Df have  5 *a's*, the solution is to eliminate the first two set of pairs of *a's* and leave the last *a* (order is important). The two *b's* are just eliminated because they are a set of pairs. The resulting Df would look like this:

```
   Letter
2   c
3   d
8   a
```

I hope it was clear the issue. Thanks!

Comment: If I use `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates(keep="last")`, the second _b_ is not going to be eliminated. Also, if I use `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates(keep=False)`, all the instances of _a_ are going to be eliminated.

Comment: You requirement is not very clear. There are no consecutive pair of 'a','a', why are row 6 and 7 removed? also, how do you define 'pairs'? Are they defined as (0,1),(2,3)... or (0,1),(1,2)...

Comment: I just don't know why I added "consecutive". Now it's fixed and specific @Allen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get rid of letters with even number of rows, then use drop_duplicates.

```
df.groupby('Letter').filter(lambda x: len(x)%2>0).drop_duplicates(keep="last")
Out[174]: 
  Letter
2      c
3      d
8      a
```

Comment: Smooth, clever and fancy. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped.